# knife bootstrap: "ERROR: SSL Error connecting"

Tags: chef-infra

While trying to bootstrap a new SERVER:

```
Chef-Workstation:~ # knife bootstrap SERVER -N SERVER -E PROJECTNAMEHERE -x USERNAMEHERE-A --sudo --verbose
Connecting to SERVER
SERVER Starting first Chef Client run...
SERVER Starting Chef Client, version 12.19.36
SERVER Creating a new client identity for SERVER using the validator key.
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: Chef-Server - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
SERVER
SERVER ================================================================================
SERVER Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "SERVER"
SERVER ================================================================================
SERVER
SERVER Platform:
SERVER ---------
SERVER x86_64-linux-gnu
SERVER
SERVER
SERVER Running handlers:
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
SERVER Running handlers complete
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
SERVER Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://Chef-Server/clients - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
SERVER [2019-04-01T14:52:54+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef-Workstation:~ #
```

But I already have the:

```
grep -i ssl .chef/knife.rb
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

And also:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect "Chef-Server:443" < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' | tee -a /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

I think it is a software bug, or what else am I missing?

**The Question**: why is knife giving SSL issue, while I stated in the config file that don't bother on valid SSL certs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded chef-client version from 12 to 11 on the node which I needed to register.